# Htaccess - Remove PHP extension

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

The htaccess below is used to remove the `.php` extension and to add `http://www` to the URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The PHP extension gets removed but only if the URL looks like this:

```
- example.com/test
- www.example.com/test 
- http://www.example.com/test
```

For this one the .php extension gets not removed:

```
 http://example.com/test
```

What do I need to add to my .htaccess file to make it work for all variants?